# How to control the duration of a Worker or BLE scan

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am making an app with a Worker (for background processes) that will wake up every fifteen minutes, perform a BLE scan, analyze the data from the BLE scan, and then wait fifteen minutes before doing it all again. Is there a way I can control the duration of either the Worker or the scan so I can make it scan longer or shorter according to my needs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Android Developer Guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/find-ble-devices#kotlin) has an example showing how to set the scan period:

```
private val bluetoothLeScanner = bluetoothAdapter.bluetoothLeScanner
private var scanning = false
private val handler = Handler()

// Stops scanning after 10 seconds.
private val SCAN_PERIOD: Long = 10000

private fun scanLeDevice() {
    if (!scanning) { // Stops scanning after a pre-defined scan period.
        handler.postDelayed({
            scanning = false
            bluetoothLeScanner.stopScan(leScanCallback)
        }, SCAN_PERIOD)
        scanning = true
        bluetoothLeScanner.startScan(leScanCallback)
    } else {
        scanning = false
        bluetoothLeScanner.stopScan(leScanCallback)
    }
}
```

Comment: I just found in the documentation for the [handler#postDelayed](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler#postDelayed(java.lang.Runnable,%20long)) function that the SCAN_PERIOD parameter here is actually a delay parameter and not a duration parameter. That would mean that the function would run after a defined delay, but not for a defined period. Am I understanding that correctly? Obviously, this would be a problem with Google's documentation, not with your answer.

Comment: No, you are reading the documentation correctly, but not the example. The call to `bluetoothLeScanner.startScan` is not inside the handler, it will be called directly. The handler just contains the calls to `scanning = false` and `bluetoothLeScanner.stopScan` which are delayed by `SCAN_PERIOD`. That means the scan starts and gets stopped after 10 seconds